# Can't send a correct POST request in Java (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http-post

I'm creating an app for asking/answering questions. 
I have a problem with POST request when I ask questions.

I've tried to use something like this in terminal

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"firstName":"Chris", "lastName": "Chang", "email": "support@mlab.com"}' http://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/contacts
```

and it worked good.

But when I try to send a POST request in AndroidStudio my parameters (such as name, lastname, email and etc) won't send. 
I tried to use https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request. The request is send (I know that because it shows the date of the request) but without any parameters.

What should be changed in my code so it would work correctly?

```
Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
data.put("firstName", "Gena");
data.put("lastName", "Bukin");
if (HttpRequest.post("https://safe-citadel-91138.herokuapp.com/questions").form(data).created())
System.out.println("User was created");
```

Comment: Information that is in Hashmap isn't send to the server (Or maybe it's send, but the request isn't created correctly)

Comment: Did you try sending it using Volley?

Comment: If you go to [link](https://safe-citadel-91138.herokuapp.com/questions) you can see, that first 3 requests were send from the terminal, and the other ones were send from Java

Comment: @ValentinaPakhomova if your content type is app json it wont accept your key pair values as request i guess!!

Comment: Have you tried retrofit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried to create an User and it worked. You can refresh the [link](https://safe-citadel-91138.herokuapp.com/questions) u have shared to check the created User.

This is what I have tried

```
String endPoint= "https://safe-citadel-91138.herokuapp.com/questions";
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(endPoint);
            post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

            obj.put("firstName", "TESTF");
            obj.put("lastName", "TESTL");
            obj.put("email", "support@mlab.com");

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(obj.toString()); 
            post.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
}catch (Exception e){

        }
```

**UPDATE**

BTW I have used json jar from [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/org.json/org.json.jar.zip) link

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked!! by the way, android had removed support for the Apache HTTP client

Comment: @ValentinaPakhomova glad! that helped!!

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
params.put("firstName", "Gena");
params.put("lastName", "Bukin");


JSONObject jsonObject = POST("https://safe-citadel-91138.herokuapp.com/questions", params);
    /**
         * Method allows to HTTP POST request to the server to send data to a specified resource
         * @param serverURL URL of the API to be requested
         * @param params parameter that are to be send in the "body" of the request Ex: parameter=value&amp;also=another
         * returns response as a JSON object
         */
        public JSONObject POST(String serverURL, Map<String, Object> params) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(serverURL);

                Log.e(TAG, params.toString());
                StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
                    if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                    postData.append('=');
                    postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
                }
                Log.e("POST", serverURL + ":" + params.toString());
                byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);
                connection.connect();

                int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                }
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonObject;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your `curl` requests sends the user data in JSON format in the request body. Your Java code tries to send the data in the request as form data which is something different and probably not accepted by the server.

You might need to change your code to use the `HttpRequest.send(...)` method instead of `form`:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("firstName", "Gena");
json.put("lastName", "Bukin");
json.put("email", "support@mlab.com");

HttpRequest
    .post("https://safe-citadel-91138.herokuapp.com/questions")
    .contentType("application/json")
    .send(json.toString());
```

Furthermore in the `curl` call you are using accesses a different url than in the Java snippet `http://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/contacts` vs `https://safe-citadel-91138.herokuapp.com/questions` maybe you are talking to the wrong endpoint as well?

You might want to take a look at some Java to JSON mapping library like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for the transformation of your Java objects to proper JSON or use Android's `JSONObject` class.

**UPDATE**:

- Added link to gson for JSON mapping
- Updated code snippet to use `JSONObject` for the JSON mapping

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it'll work

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url_, JSONObject jsonObject) {

    try {
        URLConnection urlConn;
        DataOutputStream printout;

        URL url = new URL(url_);
        urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoInput(true);
        urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        urlConn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "token"); // If Applicable 
        urlConn.connect();
        printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        printout.writeBytes(jsonObject.toString());
        printout.flush();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        printout.close();
        reader.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Applog.e("response", jObj + "");
    return jObj;

}
```