# How to send data in json format using AndroidAsyncHttp

Tags: java, android, json, android-async-http, loopj

I am trying to send data via post method of AsyncHttpClient in json format to server, server accept this format

```
{
  email : 'foo@bar.com'
  password:'xxxxxx'
  'username:'John Doe'
  'lastname:'john'
}
```

and this is my code

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("last_name","Karimi");
params.put("username","zahid");
params.put("email","zahid.omerzad@gmail.com");
params.put("password","1234566");

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(params.toString());
Log.d("entity3",entity+"");

String url = "http://192.168.100.12/users";

client.post(context, url, entity, "application/json", handler);
```

when I log the entity the result is shown as below

```
[Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1,Content-Length: 496,Chunked: false]
```

please help me?

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37525540/3117966)

Comment: check my answer for same question at below link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37468403/post-request-with-json-body-in-volley-android/37475649#37475649

Comment: I am not using volley, I am using AsyncHttpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use this `AsyncHttpClient`

the way i send json data is

```
   // postData = your json data

    ByteArrayEntity entity = null;
    try {
        entity = new ByteArrayEntity(postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

    asyncHttpClient.post(getActivity(), url, entity, "application/json", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

Which works fine for me.. hope this will help..

Answer (score 0):

JSON format needs to complete the conversion server, the client only needs to be one by one in the http-body can be.